# How do I handle Multi Select Fields using Rest API?

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest

A couple of my rows are Multi Select Rows. When I make this call nothing returns for that row. How do would I handle the multi-value field?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $.ajax({
          url: "https://gumdropsgc.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Modules')/items(1)",
          type: "GET",
          headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
          cache:false,                
          success: function(data){
              console.log(data);
              var html = "<table border='0'>";
              $(data.d.results[0]).each(function(){
              html = html + "<tr><td>" + this.Title + "</td></tr>" +
                  "<tr><td><h2>" + "Roles           :" + 
                  "   " + this.Roles + "</h2></td></tr>";
              });
              html += "</table>";
              $("#listResult").html(html)
          }
    });
</script>

<div id="listResult"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the value of `this.Roles`?  It should be an object or an array (or an array of objects?).  Cannot recall, but adding a breakpoint and checking the value should give you the info you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MultiSelect data will be returned in following JSON format

```
"Roles": {
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "Collection(Edm.String)"
    },
    "results": [
        "Enter Choice #1",
        "Enter Choice #2"
    ]
},
```

If you want to pull it, then you should use

```
var roles = '';
for(i=0; i < this.Roles.results.length; i++) {
    roles += this.Roles.results[i];
}
```

Comment: Amal,

Thanks, I was able to drop just add. this.Roles.results in the current code to pull multi select filed data. This may come in handy during the clean up process.

Answer (score 2):

Values for a multi-select field should come back as a Collection type. The values for the Collection are available from the results property which is an array.

Here's an example. My multi-select field is Color.

[image]

```
var call = jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var message = jQuery("#message");
        message.text("Items");
        jQuery.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
            message.append("<br/>");
            var item = String.format("{0}, [{1}]",
                value.Title, value.Color.results.join(","));
            message.append(item);
        });
    },
    fail: failHandler
});
```

Comment: Rob,

Thanks for the response. I'll need to recode my SP2013 Online page a bit to try this out. I'll make note of it and give it a go in a bit.