# How to select multiple values in dropdowns in datatable for Sharepoint 13 list?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-list, datatable, sharepoint-list-filter

I have a list in SharePoint 13. The list is customized using Data
table.Currently I have three filters with dropdown option. I want to select multiple option in the dropdown and show the result in the list. 
Below is the code used:

```
<div class="" style="float:right; padding:0px 5px 5px 0px;"><a href="javascript:resetFilters()">Reset filters</a></div>
<br/><br/>

<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="theResults">
<thead>

<th width="20%">Date</th>

<th width="20%">Category</th>

<th width="60%">Title and description</th>
</thead>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

function loadTable(theFilter,flag) {
if(theFilter != '&$filter=') { 
theFilter += " and ";
} 
theFilter += "Category ne ''";
//theFilter += "$orderby=Date";
// theFilter += "(SupportType eq 'none')&$orderby=sortorder";

var call = $.ajax({
url: strURL + theFilter,
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
headers: {
   Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
}
});

call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR) {
if(flag==true) {
   for (i = 0; i < fieldlist.length; i++) {
                  $( 'select[name="' + fieldlist[i][0]+ '"]' ).append( createFilters(data,fieldlist[i][0]) );        
   }
}
$('#theResults').dataTable({
   "bDestroy": true,
   "bProcessing": true,
   "sScrollY": "800px",
   "aLengthMenu": [[20, 40, 60], [20, 40, 60]],
   "iDisplayLength": 20,
   "aaData": data.d.results,
   "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
   "aoColumns": [


      { "mData": "Date", "sDefaultContent": "" },
       //{ "mData": "Country_x0020_of_x0020_Origin", "sDefaultContent": "" },
       { "mData": "Category", "sDefaultContent": "" },
       //{ "mData": "Industry", "sDefaultContent": "" },
        { "mData": "Title0", "sDefaultContent": "" },
   ]
});
});

call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
alert("Error retrieving Tasks: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});
}

var fieldlist = [ ["Country_x0020_of_x0020_Origin","Source"], ["Category"], ["Industry","Industry/Sector"] ]


var filterField = "";
var filterText = "";

/* SharePoint list URL*/
var strURL = "list_URL')/items?$top=1000";

builddropdowns();
filterPipeline();

</script>
```

Comment: You can check the below answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130111/how-do-i-handle-multi-select-fields-using-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your `<select>` elements anywhere, although I'm guessing that maybe they get added dynamically in the `builddropdowns()` function?

Certainly you do end up with some `<select>` elements at some point because you are selecting them with the line:

```
$( 'select[name="' + fieldlist[i][0]+ '"]' ).append( createFilters(data,fieldlist[i][0]) );
```

You could add the `multiple` attribute to the `<select>`s to get native HTML support for multiple selections, which would look like

```
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect" multiple>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

although that will change the rendering of the control from a drop-down menu to a kind of scrollable small textbox.  You can see how that looks by going [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp) and clicking the "try it yourself" button.

However, you are clearly already using jQuery, so you could consider using the jQuery plug-in library [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to get much slicker multiple select controls.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, the dropdown does not show up on the page. I added the <Select> tag where the <script> tag ends. Not sure if I am adding it at the correct place :(.